# Trying to find org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: intellij-idea, hadoop

I'm trying to create a simple project with hadoop. I am new to IntelliJ and am trying to set the classpath to org.apache.hadoop.io. But what jar has this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The [map reduce tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html) had a sample javac command. 
The classpath needs to point to

```
-classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar
```